# List Items of Different Heights Beneath Each Other

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items displayed in 3 columns.  The items are of various heights which is causing problems with their alignments, forcing larges gaps.  I would like them to display tight to each other vertically.  You can see what I am talking about at my site [Matthew Grenier Consulting](http://www.mgrenier.ca).  I would like the "Bright Beginnings" item to be directly beneath the "Yes We Do Coffee" item and the same in the first column.  Any ideas how I can do this with CSS?  I have played around for a couple hours without luck.  Thanks.

Comment: why all the down votes? was this not a legitimate question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `display: inline-block;` together with `vertical-align: top;` instead of `float: left;`.

```css
div.appico ul.sp-portfolio-items > li {
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    /* float: left;           remove this! */
    display: inline-block; /* use this     */
    vertical-align: top;   /* and this     */
}
```

Also, remove `float: left;` from `div.appico .sp-portfolio-item`, or replace it as well.

This is the visual result:

[image: The boxes are aligned properly]

If you want the fourth box even closer to the first one, I suggest you restructure this part of the page so that the boxes are beneath eachother (using three columns) instead of to the right of eachother, or you could set a fixed height.

Answer (score -1):

```
.sp-portfolio-item:nth-child(3n+1){
    clear:left
}
```